# Adding line break to long text with resource.resx in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have tried to separate long text to two lines, when using resource.resx file and logical texts in View.
Found that there are said many times to use shift+enter, but it adds only the line break to .resx file, but when using/rendering the text in view, its still one liner.

Tried even to change the visual studio settings, to keep tabs, but havent any effect.

Any new suggestion how to fix this?

```
Resource.resx: (used shift+enter to add line break)

LongText:   
Long text needed to show/

With to line in the browser

View.cshtml: 
(just adds one space -> Long text needed to show/ With to line in the
browser)

@MyResources.Resource.LongText
```

Comment: You need to wrap `@MyResources.Resource.LongText` inside an element styled with `white-space: pre;` (say `<div style="white-space: pre;">@MyResources.Resource.LongText</div>`

Comment: Great. That worked. Thx Stephen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below line break so that it will appear in the next line.

I am a very good boy <br /> who will sit always in the first bench only